# Node.js / Express with vhost conflict with Sails.js framework app

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, vhosts, cloud-hosting

I am trying to setup my Nodejs/Express hosting server to have multiple applications (Sails.js app type) running on my VPS but I got this error :

```
/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/node_modules/vhost/index.js:78
  throw new TypeError('argument server is unsupported')
        ^
TypeError: argument server is unsupported
   at createHandle (/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/node_modules/vhost/index.js:78:9)
   at vhost (/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/node_modules/vhost/index.js:39:16)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/server.js:46:9)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
   at startup (node.js:119:16)
   at node.js:906:3
```

Of course I previously installed all my dependencies.
My Nodejs/Express base configuration for multiple apps is good because it works fine with this express vhosts example configuration:
https://github.com/loicsaintroch/express-vhosts

So here my nodejs server app structure:

```
.../vhosts/default/server.js
                   package.json
                  /app1
                       /app.js
                  /app2
                       /app.js
                  /app3
                       /app.js
```

And here my **server.js** file based on this previous github example:

```
// Module dependencies
var express = require('express');
var vhost = require('vhost');
var app = express();

// vhosts
app
  .use(vhost('app1.com', require('./app1/app.js')))
  .listen(8080);
```

And the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "default",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Default git repository for some web applications.",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.2.0",
    "vhost": "^2.0.0",
    "forever": "^0.11.1",
    "static-favicon": "^1.0.0",
    "ejs": "^1.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.0.0",
    "debug": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "forever start server.js --prod",
    "debug": "node debug server.js"
  },
  "main": "server.js"
}
```

Error come from **vhost npm package**:

```
/**
 * Create handle to server.
 *
 * @param {function|Server} server
 * @return {function}
 * @api private
 */

function createHandle(server){
  if (typeof server === 'function') {
    // callable servers are the handle
    return server
  } else if (typeof server.emit === 'function') {
    // emit request event on server
    return function handle(req, res) {
      server.emit('request', req, res)
    }
  }

  throw new TypeError('argument server is unsupported')
}
```

OK here precisely I think **vhost package** has a problem with the **app.js** response from **sails.js framework**. Here the **app.js** file content from my Sails.js app:

```
/**
 * app.js
 *
 * Use `app.js` to run your app without `sails lift`.
 * To start the server, run: `node app.js`.
 *
 * This is handy in situations where the sails CLI is not relevant or useful.
 *
 * For example:
 *   => `node app.js`
 *   => `forever start app.js`
 *   => `node debug app.js`
 *   => `modulus deploy`
 *   => `heroku scale`
 *
 *
 * The same command-line arguments are supported, e.g.:
 * `node app.js --silent --port=80 --prod`
 */

// Ensure a "sails" can be located:
(function() {
  var sails;
  try {
    sails = require('sails');
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('To run an app using `node app.js`, you usually need to have a version of `sails` installed in the same directory as your app.');
    console.error('To do that, run `npm install sails`');
    console.error('');
    console.error('Alternatively, if you have sails installed globally (i.e. you did `npm install -g sails`), you can use `sails lift`.');
    console.error('When you run `sails lift`, your app will still use a local `./node_modules/sails` dependency if it exists,');
    console.error('but if it doesn\'t, the app will run with the global sails instead!');
    return;
  }

  // Try to get `rc` dependency
  var rc;
  try {
    rc = require('rc');
  } catch (e0) {
    try {
      rc = require('sails/node_modules/rc');
    } catch (e1) {
      console.error('Could not find dependency: `rc`.');
      console.error('Your `.sailsrc` file(s) will be ignored.');
      console.error('To resolve this, run:');
      console.error('npm install rc --save');
      rc = function () { return {}; };
    }
  }


  // Start server
  sails.lift(rc('sails'));
})();
```

==============================================

**UPDATE: FULL SOLUTION EXAMPLE**
As a synthesis of the great answer I wrote a complete case study available here
https://github.com/migswd/express-sails-vhosts

==============================================

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to shoehorn an example meant for Express apps to work with Sails apps.

If you look at the **app.js** files from the example vhost apps, they all use `module.exports` to return an Express app instance.  The **app.js** from the Sails app you posted clearly does no such thing; it doesn't export anything at all.  Furthermore, that file is calling `sails.lift`, which starts its own server listening on port 1337.

A little elbow grease can get this to work.  Instead of lifting the Sails app, you can use `sails.load` which does everything *except* start listening on a port.  This is an asynchronous method, so it'll require a reworking of your **server.js** as well.

The Sails **app.js** files become:

```
var sails = require('sails');
module.exports = function(cb) {
    process.chdir(__dirname);
    sails.load(cb);
};
```

Every running `sails` instance exposes its underlying Express app as `.hooks.http.app`, so in your **server.js**, use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or something similar to load all of the Sails apps, then hook them up with `vhost`:

```
// Module dependencies
var express = require('express');
var vhost = require('vhost');
var app = express();
var async = require('async');

async.auto({

    app1: require('./app1/app.js'),
    app2: require('./app2/app.js'),
    app3: require('./app3/app.js')

}, function doneLoadingApps(err, apps) {

    app
      .use(vhost('app1.io', apps.app1.hooks.http.app))
      .use(vhost('app2.io', apps.app2.hooks.http.app))
      .use(vhost('app3.io', apps.app3.hooks.http.app))
      // Mix in a vanilla Express app as well
      .use(vhost('app4.io', require('./app4/app.js')))
      .listen(8080);

});
```

Comment: OK testing your proposal but got error : /srv/data/web/vhosts/default/server.js:10
    app
    ^
ReferenceError: app is not defined
    at doneLoadingApps (/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/server.js:10:5)
    at /srv/data/web/vhosts/default/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:454:17
    at /srv/data/web/vhosts/default/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:444:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each ..

Comment: Sorry, yeah, you still have to make an actual express app.  I was just showing the added part.  Adjusting my answer to match.

Comment: Great that works for Sails! Just to validate your answer and the complete resolution of the subject I would like to have server.js config launch sails and non-sails (express) vhosts. I linked app1 to the app1 from original example but I got this error : /srv/data/web/vhosts/default/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:120
  var search = 1 + req.url.indexOf('?');
                           ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Function.proto.handle (/srv/data/web/vhosts/default/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:120:28)

Comment: Making me do all the work here, eh?  You're probably trying to include the vanilla Express app in the `async.auto` block, but that won't work because its **app.js** doesn't return an asynchronous function like the Sails apps do.   Just add it exactly like you did in the original example.  Updated my example to demonstrate.

Comment: You are the boss man ! :D I was thinking about something like that but could not figure it out. It is not that I m lazy, it is that I am nodejs baby boomer :D Thank you so much ! C U...

Comment: Hey Guys, I'm trying to use your example (the one from github) on a freshly created bunch of sails apps and getting the following errors:

`error: Malformed hook! (moduleloader)`
`error: Hooks should be a function with one argument (`sails`)`

Any ideas why?

Comment: @netlander which Github example are you referring to?

Comment: @sgress454 Late I know! The example mentioned in the poster's edit https://github.com/migswd/express-sails-vhosts